# How to expand the picturebox into another form?

Tags: c#, winforms

Currently, my application displays 6 picture boxes, each displaying an picture which is being constantly updating.

Now, I want upon clicking any picture box that picture box extends and fill up the whole screen just showing that chosen picture box.

Is this possible? Must i create another form to do this?

Thanks In Advance,
Perumal

Comment: It is for Desktop using WinForms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the onclick event for each the picture box  (they can all point to this same method)

```
picturebox_Click(object sender .....)
{
    PictureBox pb= (PictureBox)sender;
    if (pb.dock==DockStyle.None)
        {
            pb.dock=DockStyle.Fill;
            pb.BringToFront();
        } 
    else
        pb.dock=DockStyle.None;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not seeing any code, here is how you can programmatically change a picture box on click.

```
pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
```

So you need to create a on click event handler and call your picture box's Dock function like the above.

*update in response to comments*

There is a `DockStyle.None` to revert the picture back to original size.

If i understand you correctly, you want to have 6 pictures and then when you click one it fills, click again, shrinks, click another one, fills etc etc...

To do this, you would use the Dock and Visible properties on the picture boxes. Now it also seems as if you are asking *how* to actually write the code. Well if you show some code, I could give pointers, with nothing to go on the way I'd approach it is to:

1. Put all your picture boxes in a list and assign a state to them `Big` or `Small`.
2. Write a OnClick for each picture box to change the state of the picture box clicked on.
3. Each OnClick then calls a helper function that iterates through each picture box in the list and hides the small one and DockStyle.Fill the big one.

Does the above algorithm accomplish what you need?

Comment: Hi Joe, but using this method the picture fills up the screen but the other images are still visible. The other images are still displayed and this chosen image fills up the whole screen. How can I make only the chosen image to appear and fill up the screen?

Comment: you can hide them programmatically if there's only 6 of them `picturebox2.Visible = false`

Comment: @joe - I am not sure how your form looks like but how do you plan to go back to original screen. Here's how I think your app looks like. You have six picture boxes in a form. If you click on one that picture box should cover the whole form and so that only the picture in that picture box is displayed.So lets say you want to click on picture box 2. how do you plan to do that? pardon me I don't completely understand. But a little more info would help me help you.

Comment: Hi Joe, yes i tried your code but as stated by Abhi, once the picture box chosen and expands and fill up the screen, subsequently could not go back to choose a second picture box. Not sure how this can be done.

Comment: ok, i've updated my answer with an algorithm for as many picture boxes you want

Answer (score -1):

try something like this. the code is not re factored but I am sure you can do that

```
private bool isfill = false;

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!isfill)
            {
                pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                pictureBox2.Visible = false;
                isfill = true;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.None;
                pictureBox2.Visible = true;
                isfill = false;
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!isfill)
            {
                pictureBox2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                isfill = true;
                pictureBox1.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox2.Dock = DockStyle.None;
                isfill = false;
                pictureBox1.Visible = true;
            }
```

Comment: for 6 picture boxes it would be ugly but it would work. for anything more than that, this code would be pages and pages long...

Comment: I understand, that is why I mentioned that the code wasn't re factored. since the functionality in all the event handlers is same you can put that into a different method and call that method in the event handler of each picture box. you can even further improve the code by creating a generic event handler with the code and then assigning it to all the picture boxes.in that case you will have to pass the sender to the method.

Comment: but in every pictureBox_click, you'd still have to copy/paste the visible and dockstyle of every other picture box, essentially writing the same thing n times for n picture boxes, i.e n*n lines. btw the event handlers are not the same since each picturebox needs to know to make all the others not visible... it would be **much** less painful to write and read if all the boxes are in a list.

Comment: I am getting what you mean, but like i said you can create a generic event handler and then assign it to click event of all the picture boxes. The code would look like "K'leg"'s answer to this question.      http://stackoverflow.com/a/10815728/1386241.

Comment: then why didn't you just write what K'leg wrote in the first place? i think we both agree that is a good solution. it certainly is alot shorter both our solutions. the difference is i'm not claiming to mean to write something i didn't think of ;)

Comment: I did think and I did mention it. if you read my first comment carefully you'll find this- "you can even further improve the code by creating a generic event handler with the code and then assigning it to all the picture boxes.in that case you will have to pass the sender to the method.". But I also know that I should have written a function rather then providing a very generic solution and then asking @perumal316 to re factor it. Although, I did gave tips on how he can refactor it.

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for the help. The source code from K"Leg is able to achieve what i want. On more question, suppose I have clicked on one picture box which is now expanded, is it possible to freeze the loading of picture on the other boxes in the background? Currently it is still loading the pictures in the background.